# Tomcat --> Glassfish /lib directory

Tags: tomcat, glassfish, transition

I'm trying to migrate my web apps server from Tomcat6 to Glassfish. I have a series of webapps that I'd like to move over, but some of them use property and config files that are stored outside of their respective .war directories.

I can deploy the .war files in glassfish easy enough, but I need to put those config files 'somewhere' equivalent to Tomcats lib directory.

I'm on a scientific linux server (~RHEL) and the tomcat lib directory is as follows: /usr/share/tomcat6/lib.

Does Glassfish have an equivalent directory?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What's the config for?  JNDI names for data sources?

If yes, Glassfish (and all Java EE app servers) have their own idiosycratic ways to set up such things.  WebLogic has an elegant admin console; JBOSS requires that you edit XML configuration files.  You'll have to dig into the Glassfish docs to figure out how they want you to do it.  (I'd advise you on what to do, but I don't use Glassfish.  I don't know anyone who does.)

Answer (score 0):

For glassfish3 / 3.1 : glassfishv3/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/ext.
Which version are you using?